# My Ajax call isn't working - Trying to populate jstree via ajax php & mysql JSON

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jstree

Javascript:

```
$('#jstree1').jstree({ 'core' : {
        // I usually configure the plugin that handles the data first
        // This example uses JSON as it is most common
        "json_data" : {
            // This tree is ajax enabled - as this is most common, and maybe a bit more complex
            // All the options are almost the same as jQuery's AJAX (read the docs)
            "ajax" : {
                // the URL to fetch the data
                "type" : "POST",
                "url" : "./ajax/get_page_data.php",
                "dataType": "JSON",
                "contentType": "application/json;",
                "data":
                "d_id="+<?=$DOC['d_id']?>,
                "success" : function (data) {
                    // 'data' is a JSON object which we can access directly.
                    // Evaluate the data.success member and do something appropriate...
                    alert(data);
                    if (data.success == true){
                        $('#section1').html(data);
                    } else {
                        $('#section2').html(data);
                    }
                },
                "error": function (error) {
                      alert('error; ' + eval(error));
                }               
            }
        }
} });
```

And below is my output from get_page_data.php it's not quite working:

```
[{"id":"ajson12","parent":"#","text":"Welcome"},{"id":"ajson13","parent":"#","text":"Getting to Us"},{"id":"ajson14","parent":"13","text":"About Us"},{"id":"ajson15","parent":"13","text":"Visit Us"},{"id":"ajson16","parent":"13","text":"Bus Routes"},{"id":"ajson17","parent":"#","text":"Choices"},{"id":"ajson18","parent":"#","text":"Guidance"},{"id":"ajson19","parent":"#","text":"Facilities"}]
```

When testing some JSON data manually the below will work:

```
$('#jstree1').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [{"id":"ajson12","parent":"#","text":"Welcome"},{"id":"ajson13","parent":"#","text":"Getting to Us"},{"id":"ajson14","parent":"13","text":"About Us"},{"id":"ajson15","parent":"13","text":"Visit Us"},{"id":"ajson16","parent":"13","text":"Bus Routes"},{"id":"ajson17","parent":"#","text":"Choices"},{"id":"ajson18","parent":"#","text":"Guidance"},{"id":"ajson19","parent":"#","text":"Facilities"}]
} });
```

I have looked all over the net and cannot find a perfect example of populating a jsTree via ajax using PHP array / mysql fed and outputted as Json.

Comment: hi i removed the link from your post,because it is vulnerable, immediatly change your mysql* functions to PDO(or)Mysqli functions.

Comment: [PHP 4? Its support has been discontinued somewhen in 2008.](http://www.php.net/archive/2008.php#id2008-08-07-1)

Comment: Sorry it is more like PHP 5.2 or something I just thought that it was 4.

Comment: Thanks feroz akbar - I have changed to one of those mysql alternatives you suggested.

Comment: @MichaelDavenport, which version of jstree are you using? i'm not sure if json_data is still there in 3, and you can actually pass the standard $.ajax() options directly to core in 3.

Comment: @zaitsman I'm using /*! jsTree - v3.0.0-beta8 - 2014-02-14 - (MIT) */

Comment: My Ajax file is outputting the following when I access it directly from my browser: [{"id":"ajson12","parent":"#","text":"Welcome"},{"id":"ajson13","parent":"#","text":"Getting to Us"},{"id":"ajson14","parent":"13","text":"About Us"},{"id":"ajson15","parent":"13","text":"Visit Us"},{"id":"ajson16","parent":"13","text":"Bus Routes"},{"id":"ajson17","parent":"#","text":"Choices"},{"id":"ajson18","parent":"#","text":"Guidance"},{"id":"ajson19","parent":"#","text":"Facilities"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#jstree1').jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': {
                    'url': "./ajax/get_page_data.php",
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'dataType': 'JSON',
                    'contentType':'application/json',
                    'data': function (node) {
                        return { 'd_id': <?=$DOC['d_id']?>};
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm not sure that you'd be able to hookup custom .success and .error functions to jstree.

Comment: I get the following error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string  on line 156

Comment: This works manually  $('#jstree1').jstree({ 'core' : {
  'data' : [{"id":"ajson12","parent":"#","text":"Welcome"},{"id":"ajson13","parent":"#","text":"Getting to Us"},{"id":"ajson14","parent":"ajson13","text":"About Us"},{"id":"ajson15","parent":"ajson13","text":"Visit Us"},{"id":"ajson16","parent":"ajson13","text":"Bus Routes"},{"id":"ajson17","parent":"#","text":"Choices"},{"id":"ajson18","parent":"#","text":"Guidance"},{"id":"ajson19","parent":"#","text":"Facilities"}]
 } });

Comment: Thank you! in my case I just had to add 'dataType': 'JSON',