# Codeigniter and jstree

Tags: php, codeigniter, jstree

I want to build tree view by using jstree and codeigniter and data is from mysql database but I don't know how. I read some tutorials and demos but it only makes me confuse. Is there an easy way to make the two work together without making the code unreadable?

Comment: I tried this one "http://webeasystep.com/blog/view_article/Build_dynamic_tree_nodes_with_jstree_and_codeigniter" but its incomplete and this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020318/my-ajax-call-isnt-working-trying-to-populate-jstree-via-ajax-php-mysql-json".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found ways to create it easily and this is the code.

This is my controller code:

```
public function loadFabricTree()
{
    $data['fabric'] = $this->ModelDB->getFabricType();
    $nodes = array();

    foreach($data['fabric'] as $val)
    {           
    $nodes[] = ['id'=>$val['id'],'parent'=>"#",'text'=>$val['ItemDesc']];   
    }

    echo json_encode($nodes);
}
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$(function(){
$('#FabricTree').jstree({
'core':{
  'data':{
    'url':'/mps/index.php/mps/loadFabricTree',
    'dataType':'json'
  }
}
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a working demo for this.

Check out this: [Working demo with js, php, mysql db structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895179/jstree-show-checkbox-checked-using-database-values)

This is a working demo in php, having table structure in it. Just convert it into Codeigniter method and you are done.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer and do up-vote if this solution helps you :P

Comment: I am now trying to convert this demo "http://phpflow.com/php/dynamic-tree-with-jstree-php-and-mysql/" to codeigniter hopes it works